# Kali Linux User Name and Password

Tags: root

I Have Install kali linux in dual os with windows 10 , While installing kali I did't show any step for entering any username as well as password and now I have install kali successfully ... And now kali ask for username and password ... 
I have tried username and password like (root , toor) (root , root) , (root , admin) (root , "null") etc .... but It can't accept it ... So , How can I enter into the kali linux os ... ?????

Comment: The [default password](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/kali-linux-default-passwords) is `toor` for the live images. Are you sure you didn't put any password or hit enter? PS> Welcome on SuperUser. Ps> Probably  you can reinstall kali (it should be faster because it is already installed)... or all the other way that you can image using Kali... and that we cannot give you.